# Are links to papers via Sci-Hub acceptable?

Tags: discussion, links

Sci-Hub seems to be something many commercial web resources would try to avoid linking to: such links might be compared to links to warez. But I've just seen a question which has a link to Sci-Hub described as "link to paper without paywall".

Is it acceptable for Physics.SE to have such links?